# Get all the child nodes from a parent using mysql in a single query

Tags: mysql, binary-tree

my table goes like this

```
id | parent | node 
1  | NULL   | NULL
2  | 1      | L(left)
3  | 1      | R(right)
4  | 2      | L
5  | 2      | R
6  | 3      | L
7  | 3      | R
```

and so basically it looks like a tree:
[tree image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odG3t.png)

say i need to search for all the childs on L(left) of 1, then i should get the users 2,4,5(all the childs of these users if any) and if looking for childs in R(right): 3,6,7 and so on... is there any way to do it in a query...??

Comment: There probably is a way, but this design is not going to be fun for you. You should create a second table called node with columns left, right, and a foreign key value that is the primary key of the table parent, then insert records into node table that relate to the parent in the parent table. I think you should read up on relational database design

Comment: I have slight doubts that you can do it in a query. What you are trying to do is build the transitive closure of the “parent” relationship, and a transitive closure can imply an unbounded number of relations, which I cannot see being done in a single query. – Moreover, I agree with Ryan Wilson that the design of your table is calling for trouble: For instance to enforce that a parent does not have more than one left (or right) child you would need two extra uniqueness constraints. If your table looked like (id, left, right) you would get this integrity condition for free.